# Why doesn't Euclid prove uniqueness of a chord from the fact that length is strictly decreasing?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, monotone-functions

In [III.7](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII7.html) Euclid proves that $FA > FB > FC > FG > FE$ using the Triangle Inequality and Hinge Theorem.  He then goes on to prove using triangles that if $P$ is a point on the side of the diameter containing $G$, then $FP \neq FG$.

[image]

Why does he need to prove the second claim (i.e. that no segment on the same side has equal length to $FG$) via triangles? If the length is strictly decreasing as we sweep from $FA$ to $FE$, doesn't that make each length unique?

Comment: Not sure what you are calling the "second claim".  But this is a vexing proposition since "nearer to the straight line from the center" is undefined.  This is pointed out in a note, in the link you cite...and it is also mentioned that there are, of course, ways to repair the gap, and that this proposition is not used again in *The Elements*.

Comment: @lulu By "second claim" I mean "and only two equal straight lines fall from the point on the circle, one on each side of the least straight line".  This is proved separately, but to me, it seems to follow directly from the fact that "the nearer to the straight line through the center is always [strictly] **greater than** the more remote"

Comment: You don't mention that claim in your post.  Anyway, the argument given there is fine, with the rather strong caveat that the whole thing is ill-defined.  He has enough by that point to speak of one angle being less than another, but nothing in his argument suggests that he is using that definition (and, if he is, the proof is clearly incomplete).

Comment: As to your substitute arguement...don't forget that notions like the intermediate value theorem were quite alien to Euclid and his contemporaries.  The mere fact that the lengths on the other side started below the value of interest and ended up above it would not instantly imply that there was a point at which the length equaled that value.  Using triangles actually constructs the mirror point, which is a big win.